# Is it possible to programmatically size the field list window in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have programmatically created a pivot table (and pivot chart).  On some users local machines, the Field List window (where you drag various fields into the four areas) can be too wide.  Is it possible, with VBA, to control the width of the field list?  TIA

Comment: A good strategy: do it manually with the macro recorder turned on and then look at the resulting code. Does it use a method to accomplish this? I would guess that the answer is "yes", but then again the Excel Object Model which you manipulate in VBA doesn't seem to be updated as rapidly as the Excel application itself.

Comment: @JohnColeman This is not something that can be recorded. OP wants to change the width of the "PivotTable Fields" dialog that appears docked to the right of the worksheet when a pivot table is clicked. Honestly, it's got me stumped.

Comment: @JNevill In that case the answer is probably "no" (at least without dark magic involving e.g. window handles)

Comment: You could fire up spy++ and try to see what the hWnd handle is for that particular window (*everything* is a window in Windows), and then dive head-first into the wonderful rabbit hole of COM and Win32 - so the answer is "yes, but you probably don't want to do this".

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree. It might be some dark magic. The only thing that VBA has control over is displaying it with `Workbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList` (that I can find).

Comment: Thanks guys - yeah, I did run a macro and found the Workbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList (True/False) but nothing for sizing.  I will resort to training users to click/drag rather than employ Windows API's.

Comment: The name of the pivot field list window is "MsoCommandBar1". An entry into the "dark magic" subject might be http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=366892&seqNum=3

Comment: @simple-solution Good link -- one of the examples in that (in code listing 9.6) seems like it could provide an answer to OP's problem.